# Why mobile apps are usually authenticated via token, not cookies

Tags: authentication, cookies, architecture, token

I am currently planning infrastructure for the new project with common backend for web and mobile application. The mobile applications are usually authorised by tokens, not the cookies but I am wondering why? I have few ideas in mind like lack of flexibility in setting and prelonging cookies based authentication, but I want to know the real argument behind tokens.

Answer (score 12):

I have some experience with [JSON web tokens](https://jwt.io/). So I write about those.

***Reason 1:***

One concern is application scalability. When you use a cookie it normally goes like this:

1. User logs in. Cookie is issued with the session ID in it. The session ID is persisted in a shared session store in the backend. Cookie is stored in browser.
2. Cookie is presented at each request. The backend takes the session ID from the cookie and checks in some sort of database if the session ID is known.

So basically you have this overhead of looking up the session ID on every request. Now, this means that all backend servers have to know of the session ID - they share some sort of resource to look up the session ID. The alternative is to come up with some clever request routing, so that each user hits a fixed server where she was authenticated on. So I can't easily introduce a new server.

On the other hand a token like a JSON web token is just a crytographically secured claim, that one was authenticated (and maybe additional claims about the user). It goes like this:

1. User logs in. Token is issued that proves that claims that the user was authenticated (+ optional user info). The token is cryptographically signed by the issuer.
2. The token is presented at each request. As it is signed, we can detect if the token is valid and unaltered. Also we can say who has issued the token.

Now, as each server can cryptographically prove that the token was issued by a trusted party (in most cases on of our backend servers), the backend server is sure that the user was authenticated. However, you don't need that shared session storage anymore. So, e.g. it does not matter at all which server a request goes to. This enhances scalability and makes ops a little bit easier.

***Reason 2:***
A cookie is limited in size to 4KB. A token is not limited in size, so it can transport more information (of course a token should be small nevertheless).

***Reason 3:***
Theoretically, you can control in your web app when to send the token. It's not necessary for anyonymous resources. A cookie is sent with each request.

***Reason 4:***
A cookie is issued for one domain. If you access another domain, then you are in trouble. A token on the other hand can be sent to any domain.

***Drawback 1:***
There's no free lunch, however. A cookie can be protected by the `HttpOnly` flag, so that it can't be accessed in Javascript. That makes [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) hard(er). On the other hand this is not possible with tokens.

Comment: about first reason, what does prevent you from encrypting session info into your session id, like with jwt.

Comment: Using JWT doesn't free you from keeping state. You still need something like a session store to check tokens against. You need to keep a blacklist of invalidated tokens if you want to support users logging out or invalidate tokens after a user changes their password.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation, however as @425nesp said, it seems that we anyways need state with JWT. So if you don't need reason 2 - 4, it seems a better approach to go with a cookie, especially due to XSS benefits.

Comment: @BernardWiesner Why do you need to keep track of state with a JWT? The signature proves that the server authorized the token and whatever data it carries.

Comment: @JBaczuk as pointed out by 425nesp, you need to check if the token is still valid in the case it has been invalidated by the user, such as on change of password.

Comment: @BernardWiesner you don't have to allow invalidation if it has a short expiration time.

Comment: @JBaczuk that is a trade off that may not fit many apps specs. If your expiration time is a hard one, from last login date, it would require the user to continuously login every time it gets expired, that is just not good for most apps out there. If you can refresh the token, then you need state to check if it has been revoked.

Comment: @BernardWiesner Yes for the refresh token you'd need storage as you say, but that should be a lot less often than verifying a signature on the short-lived access token. It depends on the application.